# ASP .NET MVC3 ajax call same function from various pages

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

How can I call the same action using ajax from different pages?

```
type: 'POST',
  url: 'Notification/GetRecentNotifications/'
```

I'm currently using the code above to call my action. It works for my application's home page, but when I change to other page, this doesn't work. Can anybody give me a solution? Thanks before.

Comment: Please, put the code sample for analysis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heres what I usually do to point to which controller & action to call within an ajax jquery call...

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@(Url.Action("Action", "Controller"))',
            success: function (data) {

            }
        });
```

Use `Url.Action()` to build links

Comment: is it possible for me to separate the javascript code when I call an asp function like that inside the script?

Answer (score 0):

Put the code in a `ajax.js` file in your scripts directory then reference it in the pages where you need to use the methods in that file. Then, put any server side logic for your ajax calls in an `AjaxController` For example:

ajax.js

```
function foo() { 
    var model = { };

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Foo", "Ajax")',
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(model),
        success: function(data) { 
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });    
}
```

AjaxController.cs

```
public class AjaxController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Foo(FooModel model)
    {
        string message = _ajaxService.Foo(model);

        return Json(message);
    }
}
```

In the example above `_ajaxService` is a service layer object that contains the logic to handle your ajax requests. Below is how to use the function in your view:

SomeView.cshtml

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Scripts/ajax.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#button').click(foo);
    });
</script>
```

If there is additional logic to pass data to the ajax method that is reused, you should probably put it in a partial view and reference that from every view that needs it.